# Understanding best use of Java Generics in this example case

Tags: java, generics

Let's say I have a manufacturing scheduling system, which is made up of four parts:

- There are factories that can manufacture a certain type of product and know if they are busy:

  ```
  interface Factory<ProductType> {
      void buildProduct(ProductType product);
      boolean isBusy();
  }
  ```
- There is a set of different products, which (among other things) know in which factory they are built:

  ```
  interface Product<ActualProductType extends Product<ActualProductType>> {
      Factory<ActualProductType> getFactory();
  }
  ```
- Then there is an ordering system that can generate requests for products to be built:

  ```
  interface OrderSystem {
      Product<?> getNextProduct();
  }
  ```
- Finally, there's a dispatcher that grabs the orders and maintains a work-queue for each factory:

  ```
  class Dispatcher {
      Map<Factory<?>, Queue<Product<?>>> workQueues
                        = new HashMap<Factory<?>, Queue<Product<?>>>();

      public void addNextOrder(OrderSystem orderSystem) {
          Product<?> nextProduct = orderSystem.getNextProduct();
          workQueues.get(nextProduct.getFactory()).add(nextProduct);
      }

      public void assignWork() {
          for (Factory<?> factory: workQueues.keySet())
              if (!factory.isBusy())
                  factory.buildProduct(workQueues.get(factory).poll());
      }
  }
  ```

*Disclaimer: This code is merely an example and has several bugs (check if factory exists as a key in workQueues missing, ...) and is highly non-optimal (could iterate over entryset instead of keyset, ...)*

**Now the question:**

The last line in the Dispatcher (`factory.buildProduct(workqueues.get(factory).poll());`) throws this compile-error:

```
The method buildProduct(capture#5-of ?) in the type Factory<capture#5-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (Product<capture#7-of ?>)
```

I've been racking my brain over how to fix this in a type-safe way, but my Generics-skills have failed me here...

Changing it to the following, for example, doesn't help either:

```
public void assignWork() {
    for (Factory<?> factory: workQueues.keySet())
        if (!factory.isBusy()) {
            Product<?> product = workQueues.get(factory).poll();
            product.getFactory().buildProduct(product);
        }
}
```

Even though in this case it should be clear that this is ok...

I guess I could add a "buildMe()" function to every Product that calls `factory.buildProduct(this)`, but I have a hard time believing that this should be my most elegant solution.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

A quick example for an implementation of Product and Factory:

```
class Widget implements Product<Widget> {
    public String color;

    @Override
        public Factory<Widget> getFactory() {
            return WidgetFactory.INSTANCE;
    }
}

class WidgetFactory implements Factory<Widget> {
    static final INSTANCE = new WidgetFactory();

    @Override
    public void buildProduct(Widget product) {
        // Build the widget of the given color (product.color)
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isBusy() {
        return false; // It's really quick to make this widget
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does `Product` need to have a generic type?

Comment: @Andy Maybe it doesn't need to, but I was thinking that if I have the getFactory() method in Product return a Factory<?> instead, there's probably even less of a chance to make this work right, because then that returned factory doesn't even know which type of Product it should produce. But maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: Usually you would have a `Product`, and other types subclassing from it (e.g. `Book`, `Car`), not a "Product of X which is a subtype of Product of X" - is that even possible?

Comment: Agreed... (It is possible)... And maybe I don't need to do this in some cleaner approach. But this way, I am able to somewhat better enforce that I get the correct factory back... No?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Thanks to meriton who answered this version of the question:

[How to replace run-time instanceof check with compile-time generics validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636312/how-to-replace-run-time-instanceof-check-with-compile-time-generics-validation)

I need to baby-step the compiler through the `product.getFactory().buildProduct(product)`-part by doing this in a separate generic function. Here are the changes that I needed to make to the code to get it to work (what a mess):

- Be more specific about the OrderSystem:

  ```
  interface OrderSystem {
      <ProductType extends Product<ProductType>> ProductType getNextProduct();
  }
  ```
- Define my own, more strongly typed queue to hold the products:

  ```
  @SuppressWarnings("serial")
  class MyQueue<T extends Product<T>> extends LinkedList<T> {};
  ```
- And finally, changing the Dispatcher to this beast:

  ```
  class Dispatcher {
      Map<Factory<?>, MyQueue<?>> workQueues = new HashMap<Factory<?>, MyQueue<?>>();

      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      public <ProductType extends Product<ProductType>> void addNextOrder(OrderSystem orderSystem) {
          ProductType nextProduct = orderSystem.getNextProduct();
          MyQueue<ProductType> myQueue = (MyQueue<ProductType>) workQueues.get(nextProduct.getFactory());
          myQueue.add(nextProduct);
      }       

      public void assignWork() {
          for (Factory<?> factory: workQueues.keySet())
              if (!factory.isBusy())
                  buildProduct(workQueues.get(factory).poll());
      }

      public <ProductType extends Product<ProductType>> void buildProduct(ProductType product) {
          product.getFactory().buildProduct(product);
      }
  }
  ```

Notice all the generic functions, especially the last one. Also notice, that I can NOT inline this function back into my for loop as I did in the original question.

Also note, that the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation on the `addNextOrder()` function is needed for the typecast of the queue, not some Product object. Since I only call "add" on this queue, which, after compilation and type-erasure, stores all elements simply as objects, this should not result in any run-time casting exceptions, ever. (Please do correct me if this is wrong!)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is weird.
Your problem is that you are passing A `Product<?>` to a method which expects a `ProductType` which is actually `T`.
Also I have no idea what `Product` is as you don't mention its definition in the OP.
You need to pass a `Product<?>` to work. I don't know where you will get it as I can not understand what you are trying to do with your code

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<Factory<?>, Queue<Product<?>>> workQueues = new HashMap<Factory<?>, Queue<Product<?>>>();

// factory has the type "Factory of ?"
for (Factory<?> factory: workqueues.keySet())       
    // the queue is of type "Queue of Product of ?"
    Queue<Product<?>> q = workqueues.get(factory);

    // thus you put a "Product of ?" into a method that expects a "?"
    // the compiler can't do anything with that.
    factory.buildProduct(q.poll());
}
```

Comment: Makes sense, but then why doesn't my second version of the code work, which uses this call: `product.getFactory().buildProduct(product);` Isn't the getFactory method correctly defined to only return factories that can handle the product as a parameter?